# Prove that the Riemann curvature tensor is a tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

How would I prove that the Riemann curvature tensor $R: \scr X(M)^3 → \scr X(M)$,
$R(X, Y )Z := \nabla_X\nabla_Y Z − \nabla_Y \nabla_XZ − \nabla_{[X,Y ]}Z$, is indeed a tensor ?

I thought I could use  this:

[image]
(pag 41 in https://radbouduniversitypress.nl/site/books/m/10.54195/EFVF4478/)

and simply prove that

$R(fX_1+gX_2, Y )Z=fR(X_1, Y )Z+gR(X_2, Y )Z$  ...(1)

$R(X, fY_1+gY_2 )Z=fR(X,Y_1)Z+gR(X, Y_2 )Z$     ...(2)

and

$R(X, Y )(fZ_1+gZ_2)=fR(X,Y)Z_1+gR(X, Y )Z_2$ ...(3)

**Am I on the right track?Isn't doing this indeed using proposition 2.7? My T.A said I cannot use 2.7 it as it is stated, but I don't see why** And then how do I use proposition 2.7 then?

Comment: You can't use Proposition 2.7 as it is stated. However, if you have a map $$\tau: \mathfrak{X}(M)^3 \rightarrow \mathfrak{X}(M) $$
that is $C^\infty(M)$ linear, it is a tensor. You could ask your TA if you could use that.

Comment: Would it not be more correct to write $$R(X, Y )Z := \nabla_X\nabla_Y Z − \nabla_Y \nabla_XZ − \nabla_{[X,Y ]}Z~?$$

Comment: Yes, as @LutzLehmann suggests, please take a minute to make the math symbols actually sensible.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, that was a typo sorry

Comment: @LutzLehmann At the end of the day one ends up proving (1),(2) and (3), right? I mean, that is what I did

Comment: Yes, all you have to do is prove (1),(2),(3).

Answer (score 2):

In proposition 2.7 the map $\tau$ has values in $C^\infty (M)$.

But the curvature tensor is a map $\mathfrak{X}(M)^3 \to \mathfrak{X}(M)$ as you have defined it. Therefore you can not apply proposition 2.7 in the way you want to.

To apply proposition 2.7 we first need to transform the Riemann "Tensor" (note that what is given in your definition is not at all a tensor field!!!) to a $C^\infty$-multilinear map
$\mathfrak{X}(M)^k \times \Omega(M)^l \to C^\infty (M)$ in some "natural" way and then transform it to an actual tensor field using proposition 2.7.
What are the right $k$ and $l$ and how can we transform it?

When speaking of the Riemann "tensor" (or when saying that it is a tensor(-field)) as defined in the post it is implicitly assumed that the multilinear map is transformed to a tensor field using this "natural way" together with proposition 2.7.

**Hint:**

> Given a $C^\infty$-multilinear map $R :\mathfrak{X}(M)^3  \to \mathfrak{X}(M)$
>   we can define a $C^\infty$-multilinear map $\tilde{R} : \mathfrak{X}(M)^3  \times \Omega (M)^1 \to C^\infty (M)$ by
> $$\tilde{R} (X,Y,Z,\omega) = \operatorname{trace}( R(X,Y,Z)\otimes \omega).$$

Comment: Then what is the correct way to use this proposition?

Comment: Looks like I cannot use it?, but then  it looks useless to call 2.7 a tensoriality test

Comment: @some_math_guy Of course you can use it. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: I am confused... Why does Federico's answer say that we get a tensor of type 4,0 instead of 3,1

Comment: Is your trace the same as g?

Comment: @some_math_guy No trace is not $g$. This whole thing works generally (without any metric $g$) not just for the curvature tensor. The answer from Federico uses a "metric contraction" instead of my trace (which is just a "contraction" (my trace is often also called contraction)). The metric contraction has the additional effect of transforming the resulting tensor to another type of tensor. But this is only possible if there is a metric, while my procedure does not need a metric (you can still use the metric afterwards to change the type of the tensor and you will arrive at Federicos answer).

Comment: @some_math_guy The trace is what is called contraction [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction#Abstract_formulation) but extended from vectors and covectors to vector fields and covector fields in the obvious (pointwise way).

Comment: Does this mean that the Rieman tensor is at the same time (3,1) and (4,0) or any (p, q)  with p+q=4? How can that be a tensor should have a fixed type. Only one of this should be the Riemann tensor and the other are transformations. The question is which one?

Comment: And doesn't one always contracts using the metric? In GR we do

Answer (score 2):

In the Riemannian context you always have a metric to identify vector fields with 1-forms. Proposition 2.7 says you that a tensor of type $(k,l)$ is nothing but a $\mathcal C^\infty(M)$-multilinear map
$$
\mathfrak X^k(M) \times \Omega(M)^l \to \mathcal C^\infty(M)
$$
By the universal property of tensor product, any map with this property factors to a $\mathcal C^\infty(M)$-linear map
$$
\mathfrak X^{\otimes k}(M) \otimes_{\mathcal C^\infty} \Omega^1(M)^{\otimes l} \to \mathcal C^\infty(M)
$$

Now, if $g : \mathfrak X^{\otimes 2}(M) \to \mathcal C^\infty(M)$ is a Riemannian metric, for any vector field $X \in \mathfrak X(M)$ you can obtain a 1-form by considering the linear functional $X^\flat: Y \to g(X,Y)$. This transformation (and its inverse) is called *musical isomorphisms*.

To get back to your case, you have the curvature
$$
R : \mathfrak X(M)^3 \to \mathfrak X(M)
$$
defined as you stated using the Levi-Civita connection. You may check manually that this is $\mathcal C^\infty(M)$-multilinear in all of three entries (while the connection is not $\mathcal C^\infty(M)$-bilinear, so why?), and so it defines a tensor of type (3,1). However, if you want to use proposition 2.7, you just have to use the musical isomorphism to get a totally covariant tensor. Explicitly you have to consider
$$
\tilde R(X,Y,Z,W) = g(W,R(X,Y)Z)
$$
this defines a map $\mathfrak X(M)^4 \to \mathcal C^\infty(M)$ which can be checked to be $\mathcal C^\infty(M)$-multilinear, and so a tensor of type (4,0).

Comment: Why does a metric identifies vector fields with 1-forms? I know a metric is a bilinear map that gets a couple of vectors as inputs and yields a number as an answer

Comment: I explained this construction in my answer

Comment: Isn't that  musical isomorphism mapping vectors to numbers? I mean g(X, Y) is a scalar correct? But you said it maps vectors to one forms

Comment: On another hand if check multilinearity without using 2.7 that would be proceeding as outlined in my post right? .but what would be the definition of tensor or the proposition  that justifies such a procedure, since it is not 2.7?

Comment: @some_math_guy no, the musical isomorphism maps vectors to linear functionals, which are precisely one forms

Comment: @some_math_guy In case it isn't clear $X^\flat$ maps to numbers (or more accurately to a real valued function) but the musical isomorphism is just $\flat$ which took a vector field $X$ to a 1-form $X^\flat$